# awk prints if and else case

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, awk, command-line

I wrote the following command: `lsblk -nl /dev/sdd -o MOUNTPOINT | awk '{if (NR!=1 && $1) { print 1; } else { print 0; }}'`
It is supposed to check if any of the paritions of the given device, in this case `/dev/sdd` are mounted.

But for some reason, the script prints both 1 and 0? How does that make any sense?

I need this command to evaluate to true if there is a mountpoint and to false otherwise to use it in my shellscript.

Comment: If something is mounted you can do things like:  `if lsblk -nl /dev/sdd -o MOUNTPOINT 2>/dev/null; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami That does not work. This also returns true if a partition of /dev/sdd has no mountpoint.
Example:
```
sdd               8:48   1  29.3G  0 disk
└─cryptdevice_1 254:0    0  29.3G  0 crypt
```
It still returns true in this case, even tho cryptdevice is not mounted.

Comment: awk runs the if-statement for every input line. If all have truthy $1, then the first line (`NR==1`) will print `0`, and the rest (`NR!=1`) will print ones. If you want to test all lines, you'll have to e.g. set a variable in the main part of the awk program, and then check that in an `END { ... }` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` runs its code as a loop across every input line. You'll get either a `1` or a `0` for each non-empty line. You could

If you want to determine whether or not a device has any mounted partitions, consider using this approach:

```
device=/dev/mmcblk0
if [ -n "$(lsblk -nl -o MOUNTPOINT "$device")" ]
then
    echo "Partitions are mounted on $device"
else
    echo "Device $device is currently unused"
fi
```

If you really want to keep the `awk` approach, maybe this is what you're looking for. (I'm not entirely sure why you wanted to ignore the first line. In my tests it seemed to refer to the entire device and there can be a situations where the device itself holds a filesystem so I've removed the skip test.)

```
device=/dev/sdd
lsblk -nl "$device" -o MOUNTPOINT | awk 'NF { found=1 } END { print found+0 }'
```